# How to Access to another Prototype Object's variable

Tags: javascript

A class that has an array and getter/setter.

```
var MyObject = (function MyObject() {
    this.arr = [];

    MyObject.prototype.addArr =  function(i) {
        this.arr.push(i);
    };
    MyObject.prototype.getArr =  function() {
        return this.arr;
    };
});
```

And another object try to access to array of `MyObject`.

```
var AnotherObject = (function AnotherObject() {
    AnotherObject.prototype.addToMyObject =  function(i, MyObject) {
        MyObject.addArr(i); // here's the problem!
    };
    AnotherObject.prototype.getArr =  function(MyObject) {
        return MyObject.getArr();
    };
});
```

Now test.

```
var a = new MyObject();    
a.addArr(1);
a.addArr(2);
a.addArr(3);

// works good.
console.log(a.getArr().pop()); // 3
console.log(a.getArr()); // [1,2]

var b = new AnotherObject();
b.addToMyObject(4);
b.addToMyObject(5);
b.addToMyObject(6);

console.log(b.getArr().shift()); // error!
console.log(b.getArr());
```

It says `AnotherObject.addToMyObject()` is wrong. **'addArr' is not defined or null inside of `addToMyObject()`.**

Correct me how to access another Object's variable

http://jsfiddle.net/amhk9o2a/2/

Comment: Bad coding practice.

Comment: @PHPglue Please give me more explanations. I'm just testing and this is copied from prototype sample codes. And if you mean this is homework or something it's not. just my curiousity

Comment: You've not passed a `MyObject` instance into `addToMyObject` when invoking it, it's expecting this as the second argument

Comment: why do you instantiate the new object b but not pass 'a' into the addToMyObject and getArr methods?

Comment: I also just notice that you're setting prototype values inside it's own constructor. You shouldn't be doing this. I think you've confused using an _IIFE_ to keep a namespace clean with how to define a constructor

Comment: @PaulS. I thought that, too, but he's not. He's using a _named function expression_, so inside the function `MyObject` refers to the function, not the object.

Comment: @Barmar each invocation 1. creates an instance `myObject` of `MyObject`, 2. defines new values on `MyObject.prototype`, e.g. `MyObject.prototype.foo`, which 3. are hence inherited by `myObject` and can be reached through e.g. `myObject.foo`, this means each construction is replacing prototype values

Comment: What I'm saying is, `(new MyObject()).addArr === (new MyObject()).addArr; // false`

Comment: As you all pointed out, I forgot to pass the instance. And got to know now what's wrong or not thanks to you. This is my first try to do OOP things in javascipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made several changes through the code. To make it easier to follow I've labelled sections A, B and C.

- ***A***, fixed the constructor definition for `MyObject` so the prototype is not destroyed and re-created every time we create an instance of it
- ***B***, fixed the constructor definition for `AnotherObject` so the prototype is not destroyed and re-created every time we create an instance of it
- ***B***, taught it a new method where we pick a target object to work on
- ***C***, constructed instances, with the `AnotherObject` instance I used the new method to target the `MyObject` instance

```
// --- A ---
function MyObject() {
    this.arr = [];
}
MyObject.prototype.addArr = function (i) {
    this.arr.push(i);
};
MyObject.prototype.getArr = function () {
    return this.arr;
};

// --- B ---
function AnotherObject() {
}
AnotherObject.prototype.setTarget = function (myObject) { // extra bit
    this.target = myObject;
};
AnotherObject.prototype.addToMyObject = function (i) {
    this.target.addArr(i); // this now points to a new place
};
AnotherObject.prototype.getArr = function(MyObject) {
    return this.target.getArr(); // this now points to a new place
};

// --- C ---
var a = new MyObject(),
    b = new AnotherObject();
b.setTarget(a); // Enemy sighted, assigning it as the target!!!!
b.addToMyObject('foo');
b.getArr(); // ["foo"]
// notice this also means
a.getArr(); // ["foo"]
```

---

The previous style of writing the constructor you were attempted looked as if it was intended to be the following, using an *IIFE*

```
var MyObject = (function () {
    function MyObject() {
        this.arr = [];
    }
    MyObject.prototype.addArr = function (i) {
        this.arr.push(i);
    };
    MyObject.prototype.getArr = function () {
        return this.arr;
    };
    return MyObject;
}());
```

This is a perfectly valid way to do it to keep the namespace clean, but it more complicated to read. If you're new to constructors or *IIFEs*, I'd suggest learning them independently from each other first.

Answer (score 2):

The methods of `AnotherObject` expect a `MyObject` to be passed as an argument. So it should be:

```
b.addToMyObject(4, a);
b.addToMyObject(5, a);
b.addToMyObject(6, a);
console.log(b.getArr(a).shift());
console.log(b.getArr(a));
```

Since you weren't passing this argument, the `MyObject` parameter variable was being set to `undefined`, so you were calling `undefined.addArr(i)` and `undefined.getArr()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better example of a Constructor:

```
function MyObject(){
  this.arr = [];
  this.addArr = function(i){
    this.arr.push(i);
  }
  this.getArr = function(){
    return this.arr;
  }
}
function AnotherObject(){
}
AnotherObject.prototype = MyObject.prototype;
// now AnotherObject has MyObject prototype
```

Comment: How does `AnotherObject.addToMyObject` make use of this prototype?

Comment: Please note that `(new AnotherObject) instanceof MyObject; // true` is probably unexpected behaviour in this case